# Alternative to Launchpad Mac

Tags: macos

I have set launch pad to open by pressing space+command on my mac.  The problem is for my use case it is essentially useless except for allowing me to search my installed apps.  I do not like it taking up the entire screen at all.
It is not convenient for me having to scan multiple pages and columns/rows to browse my installed apps.

I would like a way to have an almost identical to what I have in windows.

[image]

A want a wa yto activate something that shows up as a list that with one click and if I type it searches them in that same list area.

Comment: There is a tool to put Launchpad in alphabetical order if that would help.

Comment: @jmh it would help some except I really dislike the rows/Column mix layout.

Comment: There is a 3rd party app called LaunchBar at https://www.obdev.at/products/launchbar/index.html which opens a text box that resembles Spotlight. Typing the first letter of an applications name and it immediately lists the matching appplications and hitting return key opens the app. I dont use it because I just use launchpad or the Applications folder. But after my recent test drive I may start.

Comment: I don't know of a way to do what you want. It may be possible using an automator script but I don't know how to write those.

Answer (score 0):

There is an app in the app store called Pmenu that puts a small icon in Menu bar. You define what apps and what Web sites you want included. When you click on the Pmenu icon you get a window that looks like so:

[image: Pmenu appearance]

You have one pane for web sites and one for apps. One click will launch the apps you've assigned to Pmenu or to the website. I love it and use it a lot. Makes it simple to go to websites or to launch apps. You can add other panes instead of just web and apps. It opens showing just one pane. I made it show both so you could see them.

Comment: Is it searchable?

Comment: Not directly. you define what goes in each menu. So you'd use find once and then add that to one of you menu options. You could add Spotlight or EasyFind to the app pane which will then open a search method. So you can essentially define a search method.

Comment: I just noticed App is 2 bucks. If thats a concern.

Comment: I would prefer one menu and one search.  Creating my own electron app would be easy and work if I can just give myself the time.

Comment: Sure. it sounds like you may have to do it yourself.  Sorry I couldn't be of more help.

Answer (score 0):

There is an app that sits in the menu bar called Xmenu that will give you a dropdown menu with all your apps it also comes with a file manager drop down as well, it is free from Devontechnologies  [Xmenu](https://www.devontechnologies.com/products/freeware.html) and also available from the app store [Xmenu](https://itunes.apple.com/au/app/xmenu/id419332741?mt=12) it is searchable (first letter) as is the Applications folder in finder
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Try `Alt + Space`.

It will open a search bar where you can type what you want

[image]